# Channel Form: Edit issue with checkboxes not being set

Tags: safecracker, checkbox

Have an issue where in channel form editing an entry the radios and checkboxes don't retain their value from the entry being edited. An example of the radios is this:

```
{options:myfield} 
<input id="myfield" type="radio" name="myfield" value="{myfield}"{checked}>  
<label>{option_value}</label></p>
{/options:myfield}
```

But it fails with checkboxes in the same way. I've seen a few threads on similar issues here but there doesn't seem to be any solutions... has anyone got a fix for this? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with no avail.

I ended up making the channel fields text and controlling the text input using a checkbox on the front end.